# Targeting words and integers per line text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my code, i need to input a text file where each line will read a **Last Name, Wage, and Hours worked**. Each separated by a single whitespace character.

**Example:**

`johnson 14 52
doe 12.12 35.5
smith 14.56 42`

Further i have to print a report using these values until there are no more lines to take data from.

I want to be able to assign the `name to a variable(last)`, the `wage to a variable(rate)`, and the `hours worked to a variable(totalHours)` and then use these variables to compute other things.

But i cant figure out how to target each specific name, rate, and hours worked, for each line.

Here's the code i have so far.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    data = line.split()
       for word in data:
          last = 
          rate =
          totalHours =

   #these are my computations
    otHours = 0
    if totalHours > 40:
         otHours = totalHours - 40   
    regPay = (totalHours - otHours) * rate
    otPay = 1.5 * rate * otHours
    gross = regPay + otPay
    print("%-21s%-15.2f%-17.1f%-15.1f%-15.2f%-16.2f%3.2f" % \
       (last, rate, totalHours, otHours, regPay, otPay, gross))
f.close
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks guys! it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the `data` list, like below:

```
last,rate,totalHours = data
```

Or,

```
last = data[0]
rate=data[1]
totalHours=data[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
 for line in f:
     last, rate, totalHours = line.split()
```

But there's another problem with your code.  All these items will be read as strings.  You'll have to convert `rate` and `totalHours` to floats before doing any calculations with them.